# Linux ALSA: No sound out from internal speaker

Tags: linux, audio, sound-card, speakers, centos-6

There is no audio output when running "Test Speakers" in Sound Preferences -> Hardware -> pcsp. The internal speaker worked fine under Windows. Sound can, however, be heard when headphones or a speaker is plugged in the audio jack on the back of the laptop (Sound Preferences -> Output -> Internal Audio Analog Stereo is selected).

Under Sound Preferences -> Output -> pcsp Analog Mono is selected and still no sound can be heard.

ALSA info can be found here: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=51e170cd483cf6003fa4e4cc62303c2e52b11217

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What laptop do you have?

Comment: The laptop is a VTMiltope model TSC V3-GM45. The internal speaker has worked fine when running Windows 7.

Comment: I ended up moving to CentOS 6.5 and it worked out of the box.

Comment: A common problem is that the output channels are **muted by default.** If that were the case in your situation, you'd have had to go in and unmute them (taking care to unmute both the Master and for example PCM channels), and possibly reset the volume. I don't see immediately why muted channels would make a difference if it works when connecting headphones, but it's possible that your particular sound card treats those output channels as separate and the headphones jack was unmuted for some reason.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I had tried your approach with no luck. I'm still not quite certain what the problem was, but as I said, upgrading worked right out of the box.

Comment: @bblincoe Please do not post answers in comments. Instead, post a self-answer which describes the solution that worked for you, then come back after the accept grace period and accept that answer to mark the question to the community as answered (as well as documenting what worked for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded from CentOS 6.4 to CentOS 6.5 and the internal speaker began working right out of the box.